# How to compare two datas from two class property in a list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey guys I'm creating a prompt game and need some help. What is the best way to check if a player have stepped on a map position? Here is my class:

```
class MapInfo
{
    public int PosX { get; set; }
    public int PosY { get; set; }
    public int Terrain { get; set; }
}

class PlayerInfo
{
    public int PosX { get; set; }
    public int PosY { get; set; }
}
```

- The player walks and I got the X and Y position.
- If the X and Y position are never stepped before I generate one
  terrain info (Like if have a chest, only sand or a monster).
- If the player had steeped in that map position before, I load the saved data info.

What is the best way to do this? I tried creating a list to KnownPlaces but if I try do a foreach and compare the values from player position to map position I dont know how to search only the equal value one time.

Comment: Where is the list of known places?

Comment: I'd suggest getting familiar with LINQ

Comment: Are the positions discrete blocks/zones, or are they just a continuous measurement with millions or even billions of values?

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper The size will generate by each step, but respecting the limit of the int data type.

Comment: @RufusL The list of known place is someting like List<MapInfo> map = new List<MapInfo>(); where I go store the new discovered places (new XY position) and consult the places discovered before...

Comment: I think you need to create a static list class to act as your database. I can show you how to do it if you want.

Comment: Please edit the code in your question to include the part that isn't working - we can't see how you're trying to track / query positions.

Comment: It sounds generally like you want `bool visited = visitedPositions.Any(mapInfo => mapInfo.PosX == player.PosX && mapInfo.PosY == player.PosY);`

Comment: @RufusL nice looks like someting like this... This will return only if the player XY is in the same map XY position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your problem; 2 classes where one is used to query the history of the other, here is what you would need to do.

**High level summary:**

You need to have one class that stores location information (`MapInfo`). Past records of theses locations need to be stored somewhere (`KnownPlaces`). You then need to record your current position (`PlayerInfo`), and use it to query the list of known places. If there is no match, you will need to create and store the new record.

In my example I give you the framework for all these classes. But the logic for when to add new locations, when to query them, and so on, are up to you. Since you are the game creator.

```
class MapInfo
{
    public int PosX { get; set; }
    public int PosY { get; set; }
    public int Terrain { get; set; }
    public bool alreadyVisited { get; set; }

    // Anything else you want to record
    // … … 
}

class PlayerInfo
{
    public int currentPosX { get; set; }
    public int currentPosY { get; set; }
    public MapInfo currentMapInfo { get; set; }

    public void getCurrentMapInfo()
    {
       currentMapInfo = KnownPlaces.GetMapInfo(currentPosX, currentPosY);
    }
}

public class KnownPlaces 
{
    public static List<MapInfo> AllKnownPlaces = new List<MapInfo>();

    public static MapInfo GetMapInfo(int posX, int posY)
    {
      MapInfo place = KnownPlaces.AllKnownPlaces.FirstOrDefault(n => n.PosX == posX && n.PosY == posY);
      return place;
    }

    Public static void CreateNewMapInfo(int posX, int posY, //… other stuff you want to record)
    {
       MapInfo newMapInfo = new MapInfo();
       newMapInfo.PosX = posX;
       newMapInfo.PosY = posY;
       // Anything else that you want to record.

       KnownPlaces.AllKnownPlaces.Add(newMapInfo);
    }   
}
```